# How to create own command in Ubuntu using Python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

Can I create my own commands in Ubuntu using Python, like [`ls`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls), [`cp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix)), etc.?

I have tried the below code

My Python script is:

```
 #! /usr/bin/python3
print('Hello, World!')
```

Comment: Your program is called `hello.py`. Either run it as such or rename it to remove the `.py` part. Also, you need to remove the space before `#!`.

Comment: see [this](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point)

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove space between  **#! /usr**/ i,e **#!/usr/**
- Rename hello.py
     to hello